# Filter pandas dataframe rows specifying column value till the end

Tags: python, pandas

**Quarter**   **GDP**     **Col2** 
1947q1         1932.3 ...
1947q2         1930.3 ...
.
.

2000q1 
2000q2 
.
.

2016q4

I need to get the dataframe rows starting from Quarter == 2000q1 till the last row.

Comment: this is basic indexing. there is documentation and questions abound on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

```
dataframe.loc['2000q1':]
```

Index slicing in dataframe.

Comment: This will work where Quarter is the index column. What about if there are no index columns as is the case?

Comment: dataframe.set_index('Quarter').loc['2000q1':].reset_index()
or
dataframe[dataframe['Quarter'] >= '2000q1']